# Fastest way to perform the equivalent of an if-statement in x86 assembly

Tags: fastest-algorithm, function, assembly

The task is simple: Create an if-statement from scratch in x86 assembly that runs in as few clock-cycles as possible.

- Must be x86 assembly.
- Can't use any of the *conditional* jump/branch instructions (e.g. `je`, `jne`, `jz`, `jg`, `jge`, `jl`, `jle`).
- **Can** use `jmp` to jump to existing blocks of code.
- **Can** use `cmp` if necessary.
- Can't call any external libraries or functions.
- Can't use `call`.
- Free to use any of the other available instructions in the [Intel docs](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).
- No C.
- Any of the ~7 Intel Core architectures are acceptable (listed on [page 10](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)). Ideally Nehalem (Intel Core i7).
- The `if` statement needs to check arbitrary conditions. Basically replicating the functionality of any one of the `je`, `jge`, etc. *conditional* jumps.

The winning answer is one that uses the fewest clock cycles possible. That is, it can have the most operations per second. Approximate clock cycle summaries are here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf. Calculating clock cycles can happen after the answer is posted.

Comment: , [tag:fastest-algorithm] is about **asymptotic** complexity, which can't apply here because everything is O(1).

Comment: Now... what exactly does "equivalent to an `if`-statement" mean? Would something like `jmp [eax]` be ok?

Comment: The `if` statement needs to check arbitrary conditions. Basically replicating the functionality of any one of the `je`, `jge`, etc. _conditional_ jumps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And then I realised that we can be faster, and use no additional registers:

```
cmp eax, ebx
mov eax, offset false_case
mov ebx, offset true_case
cmove eax, ebx ;or cmovb, etc.
jmp eax
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xor ecx, ecx
mov edx, 1
cmp eax, ebx
cmove ecx, edx ;or cmovb, etc.
jmp [false + ecx*4]

false dd offset false_case
true  dd offset true_case
```

Accepts eax and ebx for the comparison.
Replace the cmov with the corresponding check to perform.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much for this bit.